# Failed to create TensorrtExecutionProvider using onnxruntime-gpu

Tags: python, onnx, tensorrt

I am having trouble using `TensorRT` execution provider for `onnxruntime-gpu` inferencing. I am initializing the `session` like this:

```
import onnxruntime as ort

providers = ["TensorrtExecutionProvider", "CUDAExecutionProvider"]
ort_sess = ort.InferenceSession(model_path, providers=providers)
```

and getting this error:

> [W:onnxruntime:Default, onnxruntime_pybind_state.cc:509 CreateExecutionProviderInstance] Failed to create TensorrtExecutionProvider. Please reference https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/TensorRT-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements to ensure all dependencies are met.

`ort.get_available_providers()` outputs

> ['TensorrtExecutionProvider', 'CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

and `ort_sess.get_providers()` outputs

> ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

I understand that the `error message` points to `version mismatch` but I didn't manage to get it right.

According to `onnxruntime TensorRT` compatibility table I must have one of the following combinations (https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/TensorRT-ExecutionProvider.html):

| ONNX Runtime | TensorRT | CUDA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| master | 8.4 | 11.4 |
| 1.12 | 8.4 | 11.4 |
| 1.11 | 8.2 | 11.4 |
| 1.10 | 8.0 | 11.4 |
| 1.9 | 8.0 | 11.4 |

And according to `CUDA` requirements table (https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements) I must have one of these combinations:

| ONNX Runtime | CUDA | cuDNN | Notes |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.12, 1.11 | 11.4 | 8.2.4 (Linux), 8.2.2.26 (Windows) | libcudart 11.4.43, libcufft 10.5.2.100, libcurand 10.2.5.120, libcublasLt 11.6.5.2, libcublas 11.6.5.2, libcudnn 8.2.4 |  |

I have installed all `NVIDIA-related packages` via `tar` installation method from `Nvidia` docs.
Here are my versions:

cuda:
`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.json`:

```
   "cuda" : {
      "name" : "CUDA SDK",
      "version" : "11.4.4"
   }
```

cudnn:
`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.json`:

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 8
#define CUDNN_MINOR 2
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 4
```

TensorRT:
`pip list | grep tensorrt`

```
tensorrt                          8.2.3.0
```

My onnxruntime-gpu version is **1.11.0** because of the compatibility table above.

I am using TensorRT version 8.2.3.0 because (https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/build/eps.html#tensorrt)

> The TensorRT execution provider for ONNX Runtime is built and tested with TensorRT 8.2.3.0.

There is, however, another page that states the following (https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/TensorRT-ExecutionProvider.html):

> The TensorRT execution provider for ONNX Runtime is built and tested with TensorRT 8.4.

So I also tried another combo with TensorRT version TensorRT-8.4.1.5, onnxruntime-gpu==1.12.0, cuda-11.4, cudnn-8.2.4 but got the same error.

I'm using Debian 10.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone nailed the version matching and could share the version combination? If so, did you also manage to install tensorrt via `nvidia pypi` index (this would make things more comfortable for me)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an initial solution.

After setting the following environment variables the `TensorrtExecutionProvider` is found by onnxruntime:

`export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/TensorRT-8.4.1.5/lib`

Note that on Windows machine only the `CUDA_PATH` must be set (in my case `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4`) and path to CUDNN must be added to `PATH` variable (in my case `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.2.2.26\bin`). I did not need to set anything extra for TensorRT.